# Sf2/3 Displaing different forms for Different roles(users)

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have an App that requires a complex access control. And the [Voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html) is what I need to make decisions on Controller-level.
However, I need to build form for different users by different way.
Example: There are Admin(ROLE_ADMIN) and User(ROLE_USER). There is a Post that contains fields:

- published
- moderated
- author
- body
- timestamps

Admin must be able to edit all fields of any Post.
User - only particular fields: published, body. (bay the way, only if this is an author of this post, but this is decided by voters).

Possible solution i found is [dynamic form modification](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html). But if we need more complexity, for example posts belongs to Blog, Blog belongs to author. And Post can be edited by direct author and author of the blog. 
And Author of the Blog can also edit postedAt field, but it can't be done by direct author of the post.

I need to write some login in PRE_BIND listener.

**Maybe there is some kind of common practice for that situation, or someone can show their own examples of.**

Comment: Which version of Symfony do you use? You've tagged your question with Symfony 2 and 3, and you've provided one link to obsolete version 2.3 and one to newest 3.1

Comment: Personally I find it easier to just have two different forms.  I know you want to avoid repeating code but sometimes a bit of copy/paste is all you need.  Or maybe start with two forms and then once you know exactly where they overlap then you might be able to merge them back together.

Comment: @dragoste 2.8, soon will be upgraded to 3.1

Comment: @Cerad i thought about it. Expirience tells me dont do it this way in this case) Very many forms will be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this creating a [form type extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html)

Imagine a form type where you want to display a field only if `ROLE_ADMIN` is granted. For that you can simply add a new property to the field ('author' in this example)

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('published', 'text')
        ->add('moderated', 'text')
        ->add('author', 'text', [
            'is_granted' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
        ])
    ;
}
```

For this parameter to be interpreted, you must create a form type extension by injecting the `SecurityContext` Symfony to ensure the rights of the logged on user.

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;

class SecurityTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    /**
     * The security context
     * @var SecurityContextInterface
     */
    private $securityContext;

    /**
     * Object constructor
     */
    public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $securityContext)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $grant = $options['is_granted'];
        if (null === $grant || $this->securityContext->isGranted($grant)) {
            return;
        }

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            if ($form->isRoot()) {
                return;
            }

            $form->getParent()->remove($form->getName());
        });
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefined(array('is_granted' => null));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return 'form';
    }

}
```

Finally, you just have to save the extension as a service :

```
services:
    yourbundle.security_type_extension:
        class: YourProject\Bundle\ForumBundle\Form\Extension\SecurityTypeExtension
        arguments:
            - @security.context
        tags:
            - { name: form.type_extension, alias: form }
```

Comment: @DOS Yout think the same way as i do. That seem very useful in my case. This is strange i dont find this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic form modification seems unnecessary. Once the user is logged in the roles should not change.

You could inject the `security.authorization_checker` service in your form type and use that in the `buildForm` method to conditionally add fields to your form. Depending on how much the forms differ, this might become messy with too many if-statements. In that case I would suggest writing different form types altogether (possibly extending a base form type for repeated things).

Comment: I assumed that option. Perhaps it would be the only correct choice.